# C# Lambda to txt file

Tags: c#, file, lambda

I have some problem with linq to txt file. Txt file has next specific structure:

```
================ 09.01.2017 [8:51:11] created by VBScript ================

   ....some text

============================= END =============================

================ 16.01.2017 [9:49:09] created by VBScript ================

   ....some text

============================= END =============================

================ 18.01.2017 [8:43:50] created by VBScript ================

    ....some text

============================= END =============================

etc
```

So I want to select all lines from that file that starts and ends with "=" and select their indexes (positions) in it.

First step: I've opened and convertered it to List (cause it's easier to work with list)

```
 string filekvitErrorGroupsResource = Utils.ReadTextResource(resourceName, Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
 string[] stringSeparators = {"\r\n"};
 string[] lines = filekvitErrorGroupsResource.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.None);
 return new List<string>(lines);
```

Second step: I've tried to make simple lambda query to list by condition:

```
var myQuery = lines.Where(l => l.StartsWith("=") && l.EndsWith("="))
                   .Select(l => new {idx = lines.IndexOf(l), body = l});
```

PROBLEM: As the result, I expect to receive list of strings with unique indexes (idx), but instead I've received this:

[image: lambda_problem]

So as you can see the line with "END" isn't unique, why?

Comment: Where is Distinct() ?

Comment: Distinct() can't helps here, it only removes all irepeats of (idx=8) line

Comment: It isn't unique because it is the same string every time. Index of finds the first occurrence of the string. There is an overload that takes the starting position: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5xkyx09y(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @briantyler, that's for a string. The code is calling IList.IndexOf(..)

Comment: Yes, but the parameter is a string isn't it? it finds the first index of the string in the list (you've even said this in your answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a.IndexOf(b)` returns the index of the first occurrence of `b` within `a`, so the index of `=== END ===` is always the same.

Instead, you can use [an overload of `Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx) which takes `Func<TSource, int, TResult>` as a parameter so that you can get an index of the element.

```
var myQuery = lines
    .Select((l, i) => new {idx = i, body = l})
    .Where(l => l.body.StartsWith("=") && l.body.EndsWith("="));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have different index using select first and then doing where.

```
    var myQuery = lines.Select((l,idx) => new {idx = idx, body = l}).Where(m => m.body.StartsWith("=") && m.body.EndsWith("="));
```

Here is the fiddler : https://dotnetfiddle.net/JW7S1s

Edit : Answer updated as per comment.

Comment: Select has an overload that provides an integer as the second argument to the lambda. Do not roll your own with the `index++` bit `lines.Select((l,ix)=> new {idx=ix,body=l}).Where(m=>...)`

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Nice one !

Comment: You should update your answer. While yours technically would work, there is no reason to introduce the extra variable or to mutate it from within a linq statement (which is considered by some to often be all sorts of incorrect), especially when the framework already provides you with a solution

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that all of the `END` lines have an identical string so all calls to `lines.IndexOf(..)` will return the first matching instance. You'll need to introduce a new method (maybe name it `NextIndexOf` that takes the list and maintains a counter of the last index it returned.

Each subsequent call to NextIndexOf would start looking from where it left off last time.